# Why utorrent is no longer closing to taskbar tray in Windows11?

Tags: utorrent, windows-11-v22h2

Though there are numerous changes/shortcomings in Windows-11's latest update (perhaps Build 22621 onwards), particularly vis-a-vis Taskbar and Start menu, which irritate the veteran users like me much, but one of those thing giving trouble to me is that Utorrent is not getting minimized to taskbar tray. When open/active, it remains in Taskbar. And when you close it from the taskbar, it gets fully closed. Earlier, when we've set 'Minimize to System Tray' (and 'Close Button Closes UT to tray) utorrent's own preferences/options, it used to get minimized to tray and keep working in the background.

Currently I'm using '4T Tray Minimizer' for this purpose of hiding the same to taskbar tray. But this is not the correct way.

Edit1: Another big, very big to me, problem after this update is that we can't unstack taskbar window buttons/icons. Once we try to do that (thru some registery hack or 3rd party utility), then 2-3 thins start. TaskView stops working, and once you click on taskview, Alt+Tab also stops working. Windows Volume Slider stops working too. I've seen this behaviour over 2 diff pcs, and have tried re-installing windows several times. But as soon as I receive this update, this behaviour starts. Have explained this fully in an article in a small local website [here](https://bathindahelper.com/t/very-troublesome-feature-in-the-22621-build-of-win11/4007?u=bathinda_helper).

Comment: It’s probably a bug. Have you reported the bug to the developers? Microsoft changed something significant in Moment 3 last week that also semi-broke applications like Start11 they were easily fixed within a week

Comment: No I've not yet. But I might in some free time in the coming days. Thanks for making me think on these lines.

Comment: Is it on in Settings -> Personalization -> Taskbar -> Other system tray icons?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, yes it IS there, but toggleing it on shows UT's icon in the Taskbar tray only when/if Utorrent is running. If I 'X' close utorrent, then UT icon isn't shown in the taskbar tray. While earlier closing utorrent only minimized it to the taskbar tray (as utorrent's set so in its own preferences). Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: In Options -> Preferences -> UI Settings, make sure that "Close button closes uT to tray" is on, and "Minimize button minimizes uT to tray" is on

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio , it is set so only. (As told in the OP). All 2-3 options in UT preferences are properly set as required. Same options earlier worked. But not in the latest Windows update.